# Custom help in python click

Tags: python, python-click

By default, click adds a `--help` option that outputs a standardised usage text based on the structure of the click commands:

```sh
Usage: ...

Options: ...

Commands:
   ...
   ...
```

How to override this behaviour to have a custom help output ? What I am trying to do is to output a custom message using rich library.

Comment: we can't understand much if you don't really explain more.

Comment: The beauty of `click` is that it make sense out of the box. I think if you want to extend click, you might want to write an extension. Have a look at https://github.com/click-contrib/ perhaps you can find another project that uses the API you need.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61933678/categorize-help-output-in-python-click
It explains how to override the help message for a group, and it's probably the best place for you to customise the help message using a library of your choice

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The trick is to create a `click.Group` class and override `format_help` method

```py
class RichGroup(click.Group):
    def format_help(self, ctx, formatter):
        sio = io.StringIO()
        console = rich.Console(file=sio, force_terminal=True)
        console.print("Hello, [bold magenta]World[/bold magenta]!", ":vampire:")
        formatter.write(sio.getvalue())

@click.group(cls=RichGroup)
def cli():
    pass
```

Comment: Also works for individual help sections: format_usage, format_help_text, format_options, format_epilog

Answer (score 5):

To add to the already accepted answer, you can also subclass `click.Command` if you only need this custom functionality for a command:

```python
class HelpfulCmd(click.Command):
    def format_help(self, ctx, formatter):
        click.echo("My custom help message")

@click.command(cls=HelpfulCmd)
def mycommand():
    pass
```

Comment: You should use `formatter.write` instead of `click.echo`