# Click: How to get all options for a command for customizing help output?

Tags: python, customization, python-click

Let's say I have a command, that I can call like this: `myapp mycommand --myOption --myOtherOption`.
I'm currently customizing the `--help` output of `myapp`. I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61933678/categorize-help-output-in-python-click) which was a good starting point.

But what I want to do now is, to dynamically (so not hardcode them) get the option for each command and customize its help output. I searched the Click docs but I could not find any function like `get_options()` to get all available options for a command.
I know that one can customize the help options output by overriding the `format_options()` but in order to do this, I'd like to be able to get the options to deal with them instead of hardcoding them.

Does anybody knows how to do this?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I searched the docs again and looked carefully and found the solution. The `command` class provides a `params` variable.

However, if anyone comes across this: How can one customize the help output when typing `myapp mycommand --help`. Overriding the `format_help()` just (obviously) changes the output for `myapp --help`

Comment: You can provide pydoc for each command. Click will parse it and turn it into a help message for that particular command.

Comment: @afterburner: Yes this is what I have actually. I just want to style it or maybe add some additional sections (besides usage, options and a description). Is this possible?

Comment: You can override the click `Command` class to change the help output, similar to how the `Group` was overridden. If you wan to to do it for multiple commands, you can look into something like a visitor pattern for dispatching the right help message based on command name.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this sounds quite inetresting. Ok sry for my "dumb" question but: I already overwrite functions like format_help (in my ```Group myapp```) from the ```Command class```. This (obviously) does only changes the output of ```myapp --help```. Are there any "subcommand" specific command classes I dont know about or how to start this?

Comment: Groups and commands are similar, but even if you override the `format_help` from `Group`, commands have their own `format_help` method, so you'd need to implement your own `Command` class to override that. And even when you do `@cli.command()`, it' s using the default Click command class. You'll need to specify it the same way you do when you declare the group